# type 'LazyTrace' is not loaded

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

When setting up a newly installed Dart Polymer project from the Dart Editor I get the following error:

```
--- 5:47:24 PM Starting pub serve : testing ---
Loading source assets...
Loading polymer transformers...
Serving testing web on http://localhost:8080
in ShutdownIsolate: Unhandled exception:
Uncaught Error: 'package:stack_trace/src/trace.dart': malformed type: line 107 pos 16: type 'LazyTrace' is not loaded
    return new LazyTrace(() => new Trace.parse(trace.toString()));
               ^
type error.
Stack Trace:
#0      Trace.Trace.from (package:stack_trace/src/trace.dart:107:16)
#1      Chain.Chain.forTrace (package:stack_trace/src/chain.dart:121:53)
#2      CrossIsolateException.serialize (package:$pub/serialize/exception.dart:46:43)
#3      serializeException (package:$pub/serialize/exception.dart:88:43)
#4      respond.<anonymous closure> (package:$pub/serialize.dart:164:34)
#5      _RootZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1156)
#6      _Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:524)
#7      _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:582)
#8      _Future._propagateToListeners.handleWhenCompleteCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:563)
#9      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1151)
#10     _Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:496)
#11     _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:579)
#12     _Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:339)
#13     _Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:401)
#14     _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
#15     _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:48)
#16     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:84)
#17     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:131)

#0      _rootHandleUncaughtError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:883)
#1      _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
#2      _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:48)
#3      _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:84)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:131)
```

pubspec.lock:

```
# Generated by pub
# See http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/glossary.html#lockfile
packages:
  analyzer:
    description: analyzer
    source: hosted
    version: "0.22.4"
  args:
    description: args
    source: hosted
    version: "0.12.1"
  barback:
    description: barback
    source: hosted
    version: "0.15.2+2"
  browser:
    description: browser
    source: hosted
    version: "0.10.0+2"
  code_transformers:
    description: code_transformers
    source: hosted
    version: "0.2.3+1"
  collection:
    description: collection
    source: hosted
    version: "1.1.0"
  csslib:
    description: csslib
    source: hosted
    version: "0.11.0+2"
  html5lib:
    description: html5lib
    source: hosted
    version: "0.12.0"
  logging:
    description: logging
    source: hosted
    version: "0.9.2"
  observe:
    description: observe
    source: hosted
    version: "0.12.1+1"
  path:
    description: path
    source: hosted
    version: "1.3.0"
  polymer:
    description: polymer
    source: hosted
    version: "0.12.2+1"
  polymer_expressions:
    description: polymer_expressions
    source: hosted
    version: "0.12.0+1"
  pool:
    description: pool
    source: hosted
    version: "1.0.1"
  smoke:
    description: smoke
    source: hosted
    version: "0.2.1+1"
  source_maps:
    description: source_maps
    source: hosted
    version: "0.10.0"
  source_span:
    description: source_span
    source: hosted
    version: "1.0.2"
  stack_trace:
    description: stack_trace
    source: hosted
    version: "1.1.1"
  string_scanner:
    description: string_scanner
    source: hosted
    version: "0.1.2"
  template_binding:
    description: template_binding
    source: hosted
    version: "0.12.1"
  utf:
    description: utf
    source: hosted
    version: "0.9.0+1"
  watcher:
    description: watcher
    source: hosted
    version: "0.9.3"
  web_components:
    description: web_components
    source: hosted
    version: "0.5.0+1"
  yaml:
    description: yaml
    source: hosted
    version: "2.1.0"
```

pubspec.yaml

```
name: testing
description: A sample Polymer application
dependencies:
    polymer: ">=0.12.0 <0.13.0"
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/testing.html
```

Dart version:

```
➜  testing  dart --version
Dart VM version: 1.7.2 (Tue Oct 14 06:58:25 2014) on "macos_x64"
```

Now I don't see the LazyTrace class anywhere defined anywhere in the stack_trace package. Is there anyone with experience on this issue?

Comment: Please try to run `pub cache repair` and `pub get` on the command line from the directory containing the `pubspec.yaml` file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Günter. It seemed like a possible solution, but the problem still persists

Comment: Can you please add your `pubspec.yaml`, `pubspec.lock` and the output of `dart --version` to your question.

Comment: ok. It appears the polymer test project setup in the Dart Editor contains an outdated version of Polymer, because I added the 0.15.1+5 to my pubspec.yaml and now I get a different error.

Comment: If you set the version to `any` you might get outdated versions. When you run `pub upgrade` the output shows where newer versions are available. If you want the newer versions you have to add more specific versions constraints to the dependency like `polymer: '>= 0.15.1+5'`.

Comment: Thanks Günter. I got this sorted now.